# javascript: when mouseover to cluster, there will be popup but when zoomed in, the cluster will expand but the popup is stil there

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a clustermouseover event for markersCluster, and when the mouse over to the cluster, there will be popup. but when i zoom to the cluster, it will expands from this *(cluster)* : [image: from this cluster] [image: from this cluster second photo]

to this *(expanded cluster)* : [image: to this cluster] and this (the popup is same from the second photo above) [image].

**So what i need to do is when the cluster expands like the second photo (expanded cluster), the popup will close automatically. is there a way for this problem that will not solve using clustermouseout?**

this is the code for my clustermouseover:

```
markersCluster.on('clustermouseover', function(e){
        var latLng = e.layer.getLatLng();


        var cluster = e.layer.getAllChildMarkers();
        var titles = "";
        //Show all desription under cluster
        titles += "<ul style='font-size:11px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px; margin-bottom: 0px;'>";
        for(var i=0; i<cluster.length; i++){
            console.log("cluster[i]: ", cluster[i]._tooltip._content);
            var labelContent = cluster[i]._tooltip._content;
            titles += "<li>"+labelContent+"</li>";
        }
        titles += "</ul>";


        popupCluster = L.popup({
                        minWidth: 100,
                        closeOnClick: true,
                        minHeight: 50,
                        offset: [0, -10]
                     }).setLatLng(latLng).setContent(titles);

        mapContnr.map.openPopup(popupCluster);

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can close the popup with the `zoomend` event:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e){
    popupCluster.closePopup();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a close popup option on the mapContnr.map object, then you can try  -

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e){
    mapContnr.map.closePopup(popupCluster);
}
```

Comment: yes i tried this but whenever i zoom it out or in once, it will close the popup. the popup must close when the cluster is expanded like third and fourth pic.

Comment: You must have a on open type event for the cluster. Write the closepopup code in it.